# Upload button styling causes file list to not be shown?

Tags: fine-uploader

I have defined both the template and filetemplate options for the fineUploaderS3 object.

I have been able to change the look of the qq-upload-button element, by changing the div to a button, and setting it as a button after the uploader creations.

```
    template: '<div class="qq-uploader">' +
    '<div class="qq-upload-drop-area"><span>{dragZoneText}</span></div>' +
    '<button class="qq-upload-button"><div>{uploadButtonText}</div></button>' +
    '<span class="qq-drop-processing"><span>{dropProcessingText}</span><span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span></span>' +
    '<ul class="qq-upload-list"></ul>' +
    '</div>',

    ...

    $('.qq-upload-button').button();
```

Though the button changes, and works when clicked on to add files, the files do not get shown in the list, it obviously is broken.

What is the correct way to make the Upload button use the current jQueryUI style button?

Update 1

After reading the following thread: [How to assign custom css class to upload button in fineuploader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421985/how-to-assign-custom-css-class-to-upload-button-in-fineuploader?rq=1)

It appeared as though the upload button would be very problematic to try to change into a normal jQueryUI button.

So I solved the problem by changing the upload button to 'display:none;', created my own generic jQueryUI button, on the clicking of my button, send a click to the hidden button.

Solution:

```
    <button id="addFiles">Add Files</button>

    ...

    template: '<div class="qq-uploader">' +
    '<div class="qq-upload-drop-area"><span>{dragZoneText}</span></div>' +
    '<div class="qq-upload-button" style="display:none;"><div>{uploadButtonText}</div></div>' +
    '<span class="qq-drop-processing"><span>{dropProcessingText}</span><span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span></span>' +
    '<ul class="qq-upload-list"></ul>' +
    '</div>',

    ...            

    $('#addFiles').click(function() {
    $(".qq-uploader input").click();
    });
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer so others may benefit.

Comment: Your approach will not work in IE9 and older due to security restrictions enforced in those browsers.  We'll look into the issue with jQuery UI buttons shortly...

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will not work on IE9 and older since programmatically clicking an input element is not allowed in those browsers.

Using a `button` element as your upload button will not work on IE9 and below because those browsers intercept change events on `button` elements before Fine Uploader is able to. Also, the jQuery-UI button constructor must add some logic that intercepts events too because I needed to instantiate it **before** Fine Uploader. Possibly related to an [earlier question regarding Bootstrap's button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18495838/2405667).

The cross-browser solution would be to first render your button as a `div` instead of a `button`, then instantiate jQuery-UI's `button()` on that element, then instantiate an instance of Fine Uploader with the `button` option set as that element. Also, with the changes I've proposed, you can do away with the `template` option. Fine Uploader has some logic in the default template which adds or removes its own button element based on the presence of the `button` option.

```html
  <h3>Fine Uploader</h3>
  <div id="addFiles"">Add Files</div>
  <div id="jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader"></div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Construct jQuery-UI button
    $("#addFiles").button();

    // Instantiate Fine Uploader
    $('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploaderS3({
        button: $("#addFiles")
      });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the work around to handle IE9.  Though I understand that the FineUploader project may want to continue to support IE9, is it really needed anymore?  I just checked http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp they are showing IE9 and below, at around a total of 6%.  6% is definitely a number someone may not want to swallow, however if to accommodate 6% of the browsers causes to much pain, to each their own.

Comment: IE9 is closer to 10%, and IE8 is almost 25%.  Fine Uploader still supports IE7, and there are no immediate plans to jettison support for that version even.  IE9 and older account for a great deal of web traffic, so it would not be wise to lift support for these browsers.

Comment: What is the time table for when the template system in fine uploader will be overhauled?

Comment: It's in progress now.  In fact, the develop branch has this feature completed.  The plan is to release this as part of 4.0, along with thumbnail generation.  There are probably about 2 more weeks of work left before 4.0 can be released.  I highly recommend checking it out and commenting on the [associated case (#867)](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/867) before 4.0 releases if you have any suggestions.